# Can I change a linked div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styles

I recently started working on developing a site after a work assignment, as I am very new to web dev.

I decided to give a shot with a bootstrap template for a landing site.

I have 3 sections that are composed of a picture that slides from one side and text that slides from the other side, both meeting in the center of the screen, my issue is that when I attempt to adjust the text to align either to the right or to the left, the entire page does the same as it is all linked to the same, I guess, general "class" (I hope that is how is it addressed)

Can I change the div class and simply call it on the css?

Comment: add your code like jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change one of bootstrap classes for example `container` you change styles for every place it was added. You can add your own class (elements can have multiple classes

```
class="bootstrap-class my-class"
```

and style it safely as far as you avoid naming it with names used by bootstrap.

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer. Please give an example to make it an answer and download a spell checker